# What is this 10^40 thing?

Tags: meaning, numbers, word-usage

While checking out "正" (as in 正坐, specifically) I found that apparently one of the associated meaning would be 10^40 (i.e. 10 elevated at the 40th power).

Example -[taken from Tangorin.com](http://tangorin.com/dict.php?dict=general&s=%E6%AD%A3):

sei 【正】
noun / noun with genitive case particle の:

1. (logical) true;  regular
2. 10^40
3. original  —Abbreviation.  → せいほん【正本】
4. positive;  greater than zero;  —Mathematics term.  → ふ【負】

10^40 is a pretty large number (estimated number of water molecules on Earth: approx. 4.5x10^48) and I wonder if this is to be intended as "infinite", or if not, when is this specific "meaning" supposed to be used.

Comment: This is not the only one. There are more where that came from :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is legit. From [大辞林](http://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%AD%A3?dic=daijirin)

> ⑦　数の単位。澗（かん）の1万倍，すなわち10の40乗。 〔塵劫記〕

Also, from the [Wikipedia JP page on "正 (数)"](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%AD%A3_(%E6%95%B0)).

> 正（せい）は漢字文化圏における数の単位の一つ。正がいくつを示すかは時代や地域により異なるが、現在では10<sup>40</sup>を示す。

You can see a list of these numerical terms for large numbers on [the Wikipedia JP page on "命数法"](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%91%BD%E6%95%B0%E6%B3%95#.E5.A4.A7.E6.95.B0). Oh, [here's an English version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_numerals#Large_numbers).

That said, while 大辞林 has the corresponding entry for each in the list, 大辞泉 and 広辞苑 do not list the definition for everything from  (10<sup>24</sup>) to 極 (10<sup>48</sup>) inclusive.

Additionally, the [Wikipedia JP page on "京 (数)"](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA%AC_(%E6%95%B0)) mentions that

> ただし、いずれの国でも京まで使われることは稀であり、台湾・韓国では京以上の命数はあまり知られていない。

i.e. the terms for　10<sup>16</sup> (京) and upwards are rarely used nowadays.

Comment: For what it's worth, 京 (written as 'K' in most PR documents) is the official name of the [massive supercomputer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_computer) built by the Japanese gov near Kobe (used to be world #1 until a couple years back). And the name is a direct reference to the numeric meaning.

Comment: Because its speed 10.51 petaflops = ~10^16 flop/s.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's just a number.  In theory, you could use it any time you wanted to say 10<sup>40</sup>, like if you were describing [the number of ways you could choose 45 objects out of a bag of 160 objects](https://www.google.com/search?q=160+choose+45), but in practice I doubt it would be written or spoken that way.

Japanese has lots of [words for big numbers](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%91%BD%E6%95%B0%E6%B3%95).  Actually, [English has some too](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_large_numbers)!  You could equally ask your question about [*vigintillion*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/vigintillion) (10<sup>63</sup>).  Why does English need this word?  Well, it probably doesn't, really, but we've got it anyway.

In practice, you can probably ignore this use of 正 the same way you likely ignore English *vigintillion*.  If you ever come across one of them in print, you can look it up in a dictionary.  These days, if you need to write that number, you can just write 10<sup>40</sup>.

Comment: The difference, perhaps, is that large numbers in English have systematic names: vigintillion decomposes as vigint- (20) and -illion, and has the expected value of 10^{3 n + 3} for n = 20.

Comment: yes, I agree that it's "just a number". I still wonder about what it was used _for_. Wikipedia has something about the Chinese version of these "large numbers": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_numerals and apparently number from 10^48 upwards came from Buddhist texts, but it's far from clear if there were any other reasons for needing a specific word for the "smaller" quantities.

Comment: vigintillion... the number of atoms in a trillion Earths... :-o