# Is there any practical use of the word 正{せい} meaning 10^40 (ten thousand undecillion) ? Where did it come from?

Tags: etymology, numbers

I came across [this definition](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%AD%A3) of 正{せい} and I can't fathom what purpose such a large number (10,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000) could serve, it looks strange to me that there is even a particular kanji to represent it.

Do you know if there is any context or use for it?

How did 正 come to mean 10^40?

Comment: Related/Duplicate https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18071/45489

Comment: Closing my question, it is indeed a duplicate.

Comment: *Cookie Clicker*, among other games, uses [these uncommon units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_large_numbers), and its JP version uses 正. This is the only context I know where something bigger than 京 is used "practically". Unfortunatelly, even 無量大数 is too small for this type of game, and some games have [invented their own kanji units](https://wikiwiki.jp/halfofworld/%E5%8D%98%E4%BD%8D%E3%81%AE%E6%BC%A2%E5%AD%97%E8%A1%A8%E8%A8%98).